# Microsoft gradient filter causes inactive horizontal scrollbar in IE8 with HTML5

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, filter, gradient, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate and added a gradient background, including the Microsoft filter for IE.  In IE8, when the content is larger than the viewport horizontally (vertically works OK) a scrollbar appears, but it is inactive and the content beyond the viewport is inaccessible.

The (simplified) HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gradient/Horizontal Scrollbar IE8 ~ HTML5 BoilerPlate test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    This is a line of text to test the horizontal scrollbar when used with MS filter gradient background.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#3c3c3c');
  background: #3c3c3c -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
    from(#ffffff), to(#3c3c3c) ) no-repeat; /* for webkit browsers */
  background: #3c3c3c -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #3c3c3c) no-repeat; /* for FireFox 3.6+ */
}
#topbar {
    width: 692px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this even without H5BP. http://jsfiddle.net/nimbu/rnqsW/show/

My recommendation is to not use filters :/ and simply go with a solid color for non-supporting browsers. Also you should add -o- and -ms- to your gradients as both Opera and IE10+ support them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the -o- and -ms- (I had the -ms- on other code when testing, I failed to carry it over to the post).